# Android: Gradle not compiling parse.com notifications

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, gradle

I've already looked on some other posts to stack overflow yet none have had the answer to my question. I am trying to use Parse.com to send push notifications to my applications users. I have gotten it all configured, but I cannot get the application to work properly. I am getting the stack error:

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

I get that error every time that I try to run the program.

Then here is a copy of my Gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "[package name cut out for security]"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-1.9.4.jar')




}
```

I really hope that somebody will be able to answer this. Thank you. Also, I am sorry if this is a duplicate question. I checked and couldn't find anything that would work but, maybe somebody else has.

Here is the complete stack error that was output by the system.

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:dexDebug
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1.701 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Please post more of your stack trace; i.e. the parent of the gradle task it is working on when it gives that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having the parse .jar file load twice which caused an error.. Also, it turned out my package name was wrong too.